# Is mark_immutable_if_constexpr needed for more constexpr containers?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20

The first code example in accepted C++20 proposal "More constexpr containers" ([P0784](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0784r7.html)) uses a function `std::mark_immutable_if_constexpr`. Was that function accepted as part of the same proposal? I see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) that GCC 10 supports P0784 within a set of proposals labelled "Relaxations of constexpr restrictions", yet `std::mark_immutable_if_constexpr` is not included with GCC 10. Is `std::mark_immutable_if_constexpr` required to use P0784?

Comment: Do note that C++20 hasn't even been finalized.  The features are still being integrated into GCC as we speak (well type ;))

Comment: @NathanOliver: C++20 is finalized. It's going to ISO for approval. It is, for all intents and purposes, done; they merely need to push the paperwork through. Granted GCC obviously doesn't implement it all.

Comment: I guess I should have said standardized

Comment: Thanks. So the proposal was accepted, but only as a *candidate* for inclusion in C++20? Presumably it can still change then? Or perhaps another proposal will add detail on `std::mark_immutable_if_constexpr`?

Comment: OK, my comment is out of sync...so should I take the green status implementation for GCC10 with a pinch of salt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Was that function accepted as part of the same proposal?

The function `mark_immutable_if_constexpr` is not in the proposal, and is not in C++20. It was removed from an earlier draft:

> Remove non-transient allocation handling because EWG did not like `mark_immutable_if_constexpr` and the problem of the R4 status quo is potentially difficult to evolve.

You can also see that the wording for the paper does not introduce this new function.

Comment: It's weird that it's still included in the example code and in *To permit both cases, we proposed a library function "std::mark_immutable_if_constexpr" to designate that a constexpr allocation is immutable in the context.*.  That was throwing me off.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, they changed it from "We introduce a library function" to "we proposed a library function [...] this approach was considered too brittle." It's very unnecessary subtle.